# Stringarray stays null Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, null

I'm trying to fill `tempArray` with `stringTemp`, but for whatever reason, the values in the array are always `null`.  It's probably something stupid that I overlooked but I just can't find it. Does anybody see what I did wrong or why `tempArray` is null?

Here is my code:

```
        String tempData[];
        String[] tempArray = new String[43];
        String stringTemp;
        String tempString;

        stringTemp = Integer.toString(dwdmChannel) + "," + Short.toString(ADCValue);

        if (index < tempArray.length - 1) {
            tempArray[index] = stringTemp;
            index++;
        }
        if( dwdmChannel == 61) {
           try {
               CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
               for (int x = 0; x < tempArray.length - 1; x++) {
                  tempString = tempArray[x];
                  tempData = tempString.split(",");
                  writer.writeNext(tempData);
               }
               writer.close();

           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
           }
       }
```

Comment: `if (index < tempArray.length - 1)` change `if` to `while`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That bit is only supposed to run once whenever this method is called. Besides, I just tried and the problem remainds.

Comment: Where have you initialized the index variable? Is it possible to post the complete code?

Comment: The complete code is almost 700 lines.. 
`public static int index = 0;`
That's how it's initialized at the beginning of the class.

The problem isn't that the code doesn't go into the if statement, I've tested that. The problem is simply that `tempArray[index] = stringTemp;` doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: You seem to be entirely overwriting `tempArray` at each call (i.e `String[] tempArray = new String[43]`).

Comment: `tempArray` is a local variable in this method if I understand it correctly, you need to make it into a class member if you want to retain it and its content between calls to this method.

Comment: @Arnaud , thanks! You are right. Completely overlooked this, too many variables...

Comment: I'd really suggest using more descriptive variable names. Names like `tempString` and `stringTemp` don't help you reason about what you're trying to do with them at all.

Comment: That's probably a good idea.  Usually I do but I can't be asked when just testing something. Thanks anyways though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to fill the array with these statements

```
if (index < tempArray.length - 1) {
    tempArray[index] = stringTemp;
    index++;
}
```

You probably meant:

```
for (int index = 0; index < tempArray.length; index++) {
    tempArray[index] = stringTemp;
}
```

**UPDATE**:
If your index is static and you want to fill a single element of the array every time you call your method (at least, that's what it looks like), well then you probably want to declare your array static as well.
The code as it is now, creates a new array every time the method is called.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No that but is only supposed to run once. The method which this code is in, is called a bunch of times.

Comment: You're creating a new array every time you call your method so you should fill it as well every time. By the way, where did you declare the `index` variable?